# order by string (as the column name) with linq query

Tags: asp.net, linq

I would like to query with Linq as follows:

```
Public Sub sortquery(ByVal sortExp As String, ByVal sortDir As String)

Dim datestart As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2014")

_availableActions = (From x In _Context.Actions Where x.dateDay >= datestart Order By sortExp).ToList()
```

The problem lies with Order By sortExp. sortExp is passed in as string. The string is in fact an actual column name, but is just called into the sub. I am just unsure how to get this sorted using the string (or how to convert the string to the respective column name).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic LINQ OrderBy on IEnumerable<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet)

Answer (score 0):

I think this previous question might solve your problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/233505/1720848

If you use Marc's ApplyOrder implementation, then you'll be able to do something like:

```
 _availableActions = (From x In _Context.Actions Where x.dateDay >= datestart).OrderBy(sortExp).ToList()
```